# Adding Elements Into An Array

Tags: java, arrays, addition

I'm trying to add some elements into an array with this void method;

```
if (count == numbers.length) {
        int[] temp = new int[count+1];
        for(int a = 0; a<count; a++)
            temp[a] = numbers[a];
            numbers = temp;
         numbers[count] =  (x); 
         count++;
```

It doesnt add. Thank for your attention.

Comment: Is your loop implemented correctly? Don't seem to see the loop block {} in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Two most likely reasons for this to not work are:

- `count` does not equal `numbers.length`;
- `x` does not contain the number to be added.

Other than the slightly odd indentation and the missing closing brace the code looks fine.

P.S. Instead of managing the storage by hand you might want to look into using `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot thats work. But my getTotal and getAverage method does not working anymore

Comment: @Calaquessir: That sounds like a separate question, so please ask it separately (making sure to provide enough information to make it answerable).